# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException expected at least 1 bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

I think its mostly caused due the application context file. I am trying to integration Spring and Hibernate. It's a spring boot based application.

Exception

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.intbit.services.UserService com.intbit.controllers.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.intbit.dao.UserDao com.intbit.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.intbit.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at com.intbit.Application.main(Application.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:423)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.intbit.services.UserService com.intbit.controllers.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.intbit.dao.UserDao com.intbit.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.intbit.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.intbit" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>

<!--                c3p0 config -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
<!--                Second Level Cache -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.intbit"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>/applicationContext.xml</param-value>  
    </context-param>            

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

jdbc.properties

```
################### JDBC Configuration ##########################
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mlaps
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=password

################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider

################### C3P0 Configuration ##########################
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=10
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=3
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=0

################### Second Level Cache Configuration ##########################
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class= org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

Comment: If you use Spring Boot as noted in your tags, why do you use XML configuration?

Comment: hmmm.. I might be confused then. How do I setup the session factory in this case?

Comment: You let Spring Boot autoconfigure it. From what i can see, you don't have any special configuration in your beans, which couldn't be done with the auto configuration or properties provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: I see.. Could you please point me to a tutorial or sample through which I could learn and fix this.

Comment: Go through following tutorial:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html ...

Comment: Well, that's the reference, not a tutorial. You can find plenty of tutorials here: http://spring.io/guides